# Get and format yesterday's date in Camel's expression language

Tags: apache-camel

I am using the date in a path in Camel:

```
fileName=${date:now:dd-MM-yyyy}
```

but what I need is now - 1 day. Is that possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, not directly. The date: object in the simple language can only grab the current time (or some time value you have placed inside a header - which you could do in java or similar.

But you could also do like this. Create a class:

```
public class YesterdayBean{
    public String getYesterday(){
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
        return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());  
    }
}
```

Wire it to your Camel (or spring, if you use that) registry as a bean. If you are unsure how to do that, lookup [registry](http://camel.apache.org/registry.html) and the "using" section of [bean](http://camel.apache.org/bean).

Let's say you named the bean "yesterday" in the registry,
with spring:

```
<bean id="yesterday" class="some.package.YesterdayBean"/>
```

then just use it with the file component.

```
.to("file:fo/bar?fileName=${bean:yesterday}")
```

If this is just one single place you need it, and you are using Java DSL, you could also just pre-create the date with a java processor and place it in a header.

Like this:

```
from("file:somewhere")
        .process(new Processor(){
            public void process(Exchange ex){
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 
                ex.getIn().setHeader("yesterday",cal.getTime());
            }
        })
       .to("file:target?fileName=${date:header.yesterday:dd-MM-yyyy}");
}
```

Comment: and we can call method as .to("file:fo/bar?fileName=${bean:yesterday?method=getYesterday}")

Comment: This is no more the optimal solution. Camel [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) language has added a feature to support fixed offsets with date command like `now-1d`.

Comment: Thanks @user272735! The answer is 10 years old, so updates are very welcome

Answer (score 6):

Camel [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) language `date` variable supports command with offset:

> Supported commands are: `now` for current timestamp, [...] Command accepts offsets such as: `now-24h` or `header.xxx+1h` or even `now+1h30m-100`.

So you can write your assigment as:

```
fileName=${date:now-1d:dd-MM-yyyy}
```

Note that `-1d` equals to `-24h` even not mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

I was curious about this and sought out some help from the camel mailing list. You can in fact do what you're asking with inline scripts, such as groovy. See [here](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/use-of-expression-in-file-name-tp5731154p5731283.html).

I got this to work for me:

```
<camelContext id="contextname">
    <route id="routename">
        <from uri="file://\temp\?fileName=#myGroovyExp" />
        <split>
            <tokenize token="(?=MSH\|)" regex="true" />
            <to uri="bean:filePickupByDateTest?method=test" />
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>

<spring:bean id="myGroovyExp" class="org.apache.camel.model.language.GroovyExpression">
    <spring:constructor-arg index="0" value="new Date().previous().format('MMddyy') + 'pa'" />
</spring:bean>
```

Where my file names are yesterday: MMddyypa

You would just need to change your script body to:

```
new Date().previous().format('dd-MM-yyyy')
```

You need camel-groovy (or whatever script lang you use) on your path of course.

Comment: Thanks. We've dodged the problem now but useful to know for the future.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using filename filter :

Create a class that implements org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileFilter, and implement the method accept to validate the filename

```
public class CustomFileName implements GenericFileFilter {

    public boolean accept(GenericFile file) {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); 

        return file.getFileName().equals ("FILENAME_PREFIX"+dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()) + ".EXT");
    }
}
```

In Spring config

```
<bean id="customFileFilter" class="com.sample.proj.util.CustomFileName"/>
```

and

```
<route>
    <description>Route for copying file from one location to another with custom file name filter</description>
    <from uri="file://C:\Source?filter=#customFileFilter" />
    <to uri="file://C:\Destination" />
</route>
```